# Issue. Get position arraylist in autocompleteTextView in android

Tags: android

I'm beginning learn Android. I have issue. I have autocompleteTextView with content is arrayList. Then I want to get position of element in arraylist when I click on autoCompleteTextView. Can you show me do it ?

Thank you so much !

This code !

```
/* ================= looping through All categories ==================== */
        for(int i=0;i<product.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = product.getJSONObject(i);
            // Storing each json item in variable
            pro_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            pro_name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

            name_product.add(pro_name);
        } // end for products
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, name_product);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.result_search);

    textView.setThreshold(1);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {

          //here position is your selected item id

          /*String selecteditem =name_product.get(position);
            Log.d("Test",selecteditem.toString());
            int pos = Integer.parseInt(selecteditem);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cvxcvcv",pos).show();*/

            // I want to get position when i click element in autocompletetextView
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    autocompletetextview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {

              //here position is your selected item id

              int selectedposition=position;


            }
        });
```

Comment: thats actually an autocomplete textview

Comment: Thank you ! But when I try. I see error
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "........"

Comment: can you post your full error log? Or can you say that in which line it causes the error?

Comment: When I test with log. The value I get is text in arraylist, not position !

Comment: the position actually have the position of selected array list item. see my edited answer.

Comment: I convert String to int:

int pos = Integer.parseInt(selecteditem);

Then I see error
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Quán bún Trần Tống"
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)

Comment: click on the tick button on the left side of my question.